# why can't i use next() on range()

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator, generator

I am trying to get familiar with python generators.
I was playing with the range() function, which seems to return a range object, which my understanding is a generator.
since it's a generator, then I should be able to do

```
a = range(10)
print(next(a))
```

but I get:

```
TypeError: 'range' object is not an iterator
```

why does it says it's not an iterator, since I can clearly do `for i in range(10)` ?

Comment: Ranges are not generators. People keep saying they are, but as this test demonstrates, those people are wrong. Ranges are sequences.

Answer (score -2):

Iterators and generators are different types of things (objects). There's a pretty good explanation [here](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/python-iterators-vs-iterables-vs-generators-e15b9403292e)

Comment: While iterators and generators are different concepts, that fact doesn't answer the question, and stating it as an answer is misleading. Ranges are neither iterators nor generators.